# stop emacs server being killed on logout

Tags: unity, services, emacs, logout

I'd like to run an emacs server in the background and have it persist after logout. I do not want to start it a system service since it's not a system service. A more practical reason is that I'm not the only one using this computer.

I've tried running `emacs --daemon` from a graphical terminal, and running `emacs-client -c --alternate-editor ""` from a graphical terminal and from the unity launcher, but in all cases the  emacs server process is killed on logout.

This seems to be a bug to me. For instance, my screen session is not killed on logout. I thought I might ask about this here before filing a bug report. There is this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs-defaults/+bug/1079820 which seems to suggest it is desirable to kill the emacs server on logout. I disagree: it's a daemon and should be launchable from within unity and not killed on logout. The bug report also suggests that the problem does not exist in emacs24 so is not an issue. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with emacs23 and can't upgrade right now and so it is an issue for me.

The workaround I have found is to `ctrl-alt-F1` and run the daemon from the terminal there. Then Unity has no knowledge of the process and doesn't kill it on logout. I'd prefer not to have to do this however.

Does anyone know how to prevent the `emacs --daemon` process being killed when I logout?